# Activity is onCreated() between onPause() and onStop()

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I cannot reliably exit Activities in my app. When I press the "back"-Button on the device or I call `finish()` from a button click, the activity is - apparently randomly - restarted.

Example Activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "abc", ParentActivity = typeof(MainActivity))]
public class ImpressumActivity : Activity
{
    private static int _instancecounter;
    private int _thisinstance;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        _thisinstance = _instancecounter++;
        Console.WriteLine("Creating instance {0}", _thisinstance);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Impressum);
        Console.WriteLine("Created instance {0}", _thisinstance);
    }

    public override void Finish()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finishing instance {0}", _thisinstance);
        base.Finish();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished instance {0}", _thisinstance);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stopping instance {0}", _thisinstance);
        base.OnStop();
        Console.WriteLine("Stopped instance {0}", _thisinstance);
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pausing instance {0}", _thisinstance);
        base.OnPause();
        Console.WriteLine("Paused instance {0}", _thisinstance);
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Destroying instance {0}", _thisinstance);
        base.OnDestroy();
        Console.WriteLine("Destroyed instance {0}", _thisinstance);
    }
}
```

Now, I start the activiy via `impressumButton.Click += delegate { StartActivity(typeof(ImpressumActivity)); };` on 11:20:50 in my MainActivity, then I press the back-Button at 11:20:53. The Activity "remains" onscreen; actually it gets recreated, as I can see from the output:

```
10-07 11:20:50.255 I/mono-stdout( 6149): Creating instance 0
10-07 11:20:50.275 I/mono-stdout( 6149): Created instance 0
10-07 11:20:50.275 D/Activity( 6149): setTransGradationMode to true
10-07 11:20:53.535 I/mono-stdout( 6149): Finishing instance 0
10-07 11:20:53.555 I/mono-stdout( 6149): Finished instance 0
10-07 11:20:53.565 I/mono-stdout( 6149): Pausing instance 0
10-07 11:20:53.585 I/mono-stdout( 6149): Paused instance 0
10-07 11:20:53.605 I/mono-stdout( 6149): Creating instance 1
10-07 11:20:53.625 I/mono-stdout( 6149): Created instance 1
10-07 11:20:53.625 D/Activity( 6149): setTransGradationMode to true
10-07 11:20:54.015 I/mono-stdout( 6149): Stopping instance 0
10-07 11:20:54.015 I/mono-stdout( 6149): Stopped instance 0
10-07 11:20:54.015 I/mono-stdout( 6149): Destroying instance 0
10-07 11:20:54.015 I/mono-stdout( 6149): Destroyed instance 0
```

I have the same behaviour in other Activities. I tried `NoHistory=true`, which helps, but breaks other things (I do want a call history in the more complicated Activities), with and without `ParentActivity = ...`, but I am stuck.

Update: This is a MainActivity with which I can reproduce(*) the behaviour:
(*): Please note that the behaviour I described does not always appear. It seems to appear **mostly** when I enter the ImpressumActivity for the second time, or, more specifically, I need to press "Back" n times the nth time I entered the Activity (notwithstanding that it had been destroyed each time!)

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/MainHL", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        var impressumButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.impressum);
        impressumButton.Click += delegate { StartActivity(typeof (ImpressumActivity)); };
    }
}
```

Comment: From within a blank Android project and implementing default button's click event it works as it is supposed to. Sounds to me like an issue with navigation somehow.

Comment: Any idea what might cause issues with the navigation?

Comment: Is that all code? You don't override OnBackPressed or something like that? It is hard to say without seeing all the code.

Comment: This is all the code for that Activity. Obviously, there are others; I didn't (and still don't) want to post 1000s of lines of code. Let me see if I can strip my MainActivity down enough.

Comment: Please see my edit. The MainActivity seems very innocent to me, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, that's the problem. Each time OnResume happens you wire click event but you don't release it. It results in as many new activity instances being created upon click. Wire click event in OnCreate instead and you'll be fine.

Comment: Oh, so it's the `+` in `*.Click += ...` ? So that after five `OnResume()`s, I have five Handlers attached to the one button?
(I'll try that out tomorrow and report back)

Comment: Yep, that is the case unless activity gets recreated. += adds handler, -= removes it.